# Mysql trigger issue for after update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a mysql trigger for update query. Here I am using separate update queries for user changes.

```
1. personal details
2. address details
3. contact details
```

So I need t create one trigger to use for all above changes.

This is how I tried it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_change
    AFTER UPDATE ON users 
    FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO access_log (id,action,previous_data,current_data)
    VALUES (
    NEW.user_id,
    CASE
        WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address) OR
                 (NEW.city_id <> OLD.city_id)
            THEN 'Beneficiary address details'
        WHEN (NEW.email <> OLD.email) OR 
                 (NEW.telephone <> OLD.telephone) OR 
                 (NEW.mobile <> OLD.mobile) 
            THEN 'Beneficiary contact details'
            ELSE 'Beneficiary personal details'
            END,    
        CONCAT_WS("<br>\n"
            , IF(OLD.title<>NEW.title, CONCAT('Title: ',OLD.title), NULL)
            , IF(OLD.beneficiary_name<>NEW.name, CONCAT('Beneficiary Name: ', OLD.name), NULL)
            , IF(OLD.gender<>NEW.gender, CONCAT('Gender: ',OLD.gender), NULL)
        ),
        CONCAT_WS("<br>\n" 
            , IF(OLD.title<>NEW.title, CONCAT('Title: ',NEW.title), NULL)
            , IF(OLD.beneficiary_name<>NEW.name, CONCAT('Beneficiary Name: ', NEW.name), NULL)
            , IF(OLD.gender<>NEW.gender, CONCAT('Gender: ', NEW.gender), NULL)
        ),
        CONCAT_WS(', ', OLD.address, OLD.city_id),
        CONCAT_WS(', ', NEW.address, NEW.city_id)
);
```

My problem is trigger is creating, but inser query is not working. That mean data is not inserting to `access_log` table after update queries run.

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: your column counts are 4 vs 6 I think. So in these 4 columns, jam these 6 columns. If so, I survived the create (of the event) without a syntax error. But triggers die silently, as, well, there is no user interface afterall.

Comment: @Drew, I couldn't get what you have mentioned. Can you kindly elaborate this with an example. Thank you.

Comment: I can use yours. You have 4 columns for the column list: `(id,action,previous_data,current_data)`. But the data you are providing it  is 6 columns: (1) an id, (2) a case/when block, and then 3 4 5 6 are concats

Comment: I am not sure how I provide 6 columns. Its 4 columns. Can you tell what is the 6 columns I provide? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO access_log (id,action,previous_data,current_data)
```

this line contain 4 fields
and below you are providing 6